# deleted suse 11.2 now my computer wont start

Tags: bootloader

I originally had Windows 7 installed and later installed SUSE 11.2 on a different partition.

After later deleting the Linux partition my PC now won't start. Is there a way to install both without interfering with the Windows bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

No, the windows bootloader needs to be replaced in order to run linux and windows. You can restore the windows MBR by using the win 7 installation disc and running a repair. You can find specific instructions [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html).

Comment: It is rather that the Linux installation has replaced the bootloader of Windows. The above link shows how to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

John asked

> ... Windows 7 ... Suse 11.2  ... Is there a way to install both without interfering with the Windows bootloader??

You can install Linux on Windows without affecting the Windows bootloader. However I don't know if it can be done with SUSE.

For a Ubuntu based Linux system running as a Windows application see [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/).

> andLinux is a complete Ubuntu Linux system running seamlessly in Windows 2000 based systems (2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7; 32-bit versions only).
>
> andLinux uses coLinux as its core ... coLinux is a port of the Linux kernel to Windows. Although this technology is a bit like running Linux in a virtual machine, coLinux differs itself by being more of a merger of Windows and the Linux kernel and not an emulated PC, making it more efficient. Xming is used as X server and PulseAudio as sound server.

You can probably run SUSE in a VM using one of the popular VM hypervisors. My Google search results suggest SUSE will run under Hyper-V, Virtual-PC and VMware at least.